# How to prove that eventually $(x^p/e^{x^q}) < 1/(x^2) $ for $p,q>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

How to prove that eventually $x^p/\exp(x^q) < 1/(x^2) $ for $p,q>0$. I tried showing that $x^{p+2} > \exp(x^q)$ by using the Taylor expansion of e but this didn't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to show that eventually
$$ \exp(x) > x^{\frac{p+2}{q}}. \tag{1}$$
Let $N=1+\left\lceil\frac{p+2}{q}\right\rceil$. For every $x\geq N!$ we have:
$$ \exp(x) \geq \frac{x^N}{N!} \geq \frac{x}{N!}\cdot x^{\frac{p+2}{q}}>x^{\frac{p+2}{q}}\tag{2}$$ as wanted.

Comment: Doesn't this show that $x^q e^x > x^{p+2}$ not that $e^{x^q} >x^{p+2} $?

Comment: @user228742: multiply both sides of your inequality by $x^2$, then replace $x$ with $x^{1/q}$. You will get my $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: assume that $nq > p$ for integer $n> 0$. Then
$$\exp(x^q) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{kq}}{k!} \ge \frac{x^{(n+1)q}}{n!} \ge \frac{x^p x^q}{n!} \ge {x^p},$$

assuming that $x^q / n! > 1$ for large enough $x$. This is true, as for fixed $q, n$ $x^q / n!$ is monotonous and
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}x^q / n! = \infty.$$